# MySQL - what is the best way to store different data types of a single property?

Tags: mysql, database

I have 3 objects: `Report`, `ReportCondition` and `ConditionValue`. Relationships are: `Report` has many `ReportConditions` (eg. personID, name and date of birth), `ReportCondition` has many `ConditionValues` (eg multiple IDs for querying personID). Ideally `ConditionValue` would consist of 2 fields: `ID` and `value`. As conditions of a report might refer to various objects and properties (as in examples above), data types of condition values might be `integers` (primary key ID of some other objects in tables with business data), `strings` or `dates` (no other types planned at present).

I see 3 solutions:

1. Make the `ConditionValue.value` a `varchar` and store whatever data type the value has just there. It seems the easiest.
2. Make the separate `intValue`, `stringValue` and `dateValue` fields in `ConditionValue` record and store relevant value in a relevant data type field accepting that each record will have 2 null fields.
3. Make separate tables for each condition data type - this seems overly complicated for querying.

Is the `varchar` approach proper? What would be the best solution in this case?

Comment: Depends on the operations performed with this data. Option 1 is preferred in more than half of cases.

Comment: Thanks! The extracted report object will either be sent to user as JSON via HTTP or will be directly used by backend to build a query for the database using the stored parameters.

Comment: Output (sending somewhere, simple SELECT) is not interesting, either to user output or backend. You must specify filtering, grouping, aggregating, joining, insert, update, delete, ...

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is popular, it's commonly known as [Entity-Attribute-Value](https://karwin.com/blog/index.php/2009/05/21/eav-fail/).

This comes with some disadvantages.

- Using varchar for everything means you can't rely on data types to enforce validity. For example, nothing prevents you from storing "banana" for a value that should be a number or a date.
- Varchar takes more space to store numeric or date values.
- You lose the ability to use constraints like UNIQUE or FOREIGN KEY.

However, it might be the lesser of possible evils.

Ultimately, the "best" solution depends on how you will query it.

Comment: Thank you. From your answer it sounds a bit like option 2 might be a bit better? It uses more storage space, but it will be somewhat offset by the fact that varchar is not optimal either, as you mentioned. And since on the programming level I need to convert the data to relevant data type anyway, I might as well assign the value from a relevant field instead?

Comment: You still haven't described anything about how you will query the data, so there's no way I can guess which option is better. You must start with the queries when you design a database for non-relational data.

Comment: Sorry for delay. I plan the querying quite simple - any query parameters will apply to `Report`s table only. For all records matching the desired `Report` parameters I want to extract all related `ReportCondition`s and their respective `ConditionValue`s - no filtering for these tables is planned.